# ANTLR v4: Parsing XSD datatypes

Tags: regex, xsd, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a program for automatic mapping of XML Schema (XSD) files to ANTLR v4 grammar files.

To implement it, I have to find a mapping of built in XSD types like int, double, string, basically any type you can find [here](http://www.xml.dvint.com/docs/SchemaDataTypesQR-2.pdf).

If we take `byte` for example, they can have three different kinds of signs (+, -, none) and a value between 127 and -128. Trying to match that to an ANTLR lexer rule is a pain already, as you can see from the examples on [this page on matching numeric ranges with regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html). To match a number between 0 (or 00 or 000) and 127, we have

`^(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-7])$`

This does not even yet include the case of a negative number, where the number value goes up to 128. Doing this for int or double values seems incredibly laborious. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: **Range of numbers** and **Regex** don't go hand in hand. Regex is very smart when matching **patterns**. But it's stupid when matching **range of numbers**. You will have to teach it range matching by something more longer than you currently have and it will be tedious and confusing to lookback at it.

Comment: Inside you lexer, you simply match all integer values: `INTEGER: [0-9]+;`. Semantic analysis should be done afterwards (during parsing/inside a visitor)